# How can I perform a GROUP BY query with the QuerySet API, that returns model instances, rather than dictionaries?

Tags: django, django-models

is it possible to create a list of model instances instead of a list of dictionaries when performing a GROUP BY query? I lose the functionality of a model instance when the instance is a dictionary.

```
class Product(AbstractProduct):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
      description = models.CharField(max_length=10000, null=True, blank=True)
      is_published = models.BooleanField(default=False)
      picture = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
      user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='products', blank=True, null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

      @property
      def is_parent(self):
          return self.structure == self.PARENT

class Enrollment(models.Model):
      product = models.ForeignKey("catalogue.Product", related_name='enrollments', blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='enrollments', blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

```
Product.objects.filter(is_published=True).values('enrollments__user').annotate(enrolled_user_count=Count('enrollments__user')).values('title','description','enrolled_user_count').order_by('-enrolled_user_count')
```

I wont be able to call the is_parent() function in a template tag if I use the values() function to perform the GROUP BY query

Comment: Can you share the model and current query you are using?

Comment: Which DB are you using?

Comment: You want to just get a list of `Products` with an annotation of the number of users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query will get you all `Product` objects which are published and will be annotated with the number of users

```
Product.objects.filter(
    is_published=True
).annotate(
    enrolled_user_count=Count('enrollments__user')
).order_by(
    '-enrolled_user_count'
)
```

Comment: yes this is what I was trying to do. Get a list of products along with an annotation of the number of users enrolled to use that product

Answer (score 1):

Result of `GROUP BY` is not the model instances - it contains not specific row of the table, but only distinct values of some column (in simple case), not related to whole table row (model instance) along with aggregate value of all matching rows.

However, if you want to add count of unique users of each product enrollments you can add `Count()` aggregate directly on `Product` with `distinct` clause on `enrollments__client`:

```
Product.objects.filter(
    is_published=True
).annotate(
    enrolled_user_count=Count('enrollments__user', distinct=True)
).values(
    'title', 'description', 'enrolled_user_count'
).order_by(
    '-enrolled_user_count'
)
```